# Dashboard that updates real time, how to structure

Tags: sql, node.js, dashboard

I am trying to create a dashboard app for my company that displays data from a few different sources that they use. I am starting with an in house system that stores data in MSSQL. I'm struggling to decide how I can display real time (or at least updated regularly) data based on this database.

I was thinking of writing a node server to poll the company database and check for updates and then store a copy of the relevant tables in my own database. Then creating another node server that computes metrics (average delivery time, Turnover, etc.) from my database and then a frontend (probably react) to display these metrics nicely and trigger the logic in the backend whenever the page is loaded by a user.

This is my first project so just need some guidance on whether this is the right way to go about this or if I'm over complicating it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One of solutions is to implement a CRON job in nodejs or in you frontEnd side, then you can retrieve new Data inserted to your Database.

You can reffer to this link for more information about the CROB job :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron

if you are using MySQL, you can use the mysql-events listner, it is a MySQL database and runs callbacks on matched events.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-events